# How to Access a component declared in parent module

Tags: angular

Angular component does not recognize a component declared in the module
its declared in.
I am able to use the CommentsComponent in the ChildComponent, but not child module. I tried creating  a shared module which was imported into the parent module and then exported to the child module. However that gave me a Firebase error. When i try to declare the CommentsComponent directly in the ChildModule It gives me this error:

> CommentsComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: TabsModule and DocDetailModule!

however when I declare it in the parent module only or directly in the child module it does not recognize the component

I tried many different approaches but had no luck.

Parent module:

```
 imports:[childModule  // page component with module and routing]

    declarations: [
   ...
    ChildComponent //no module
    CommentsComponent,
   ... 
   
  ],`
```

Declaring the CommentsComponent in a module and exporting it to other modules:

// Comments.module.ts:  (module being shared)

```
 @NgModule({
   imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    CommentsComponent,
  
],
exports: [CommentsComponent]
```

// child module that requires the component:

```
  @NgModule({
   imports: [
    CommonModule,
   ...
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  entryComponents: [...],
})
```

// parent module which encapsulates the child module and child component:

```
   @NgModule({
   imports: [
    ...
    CommentsModule,
    
    DocDetailModule,]
```

// the component works with firebase errors (((

```
Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]:     
Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was     
 undefined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a component which will be use in multiple modules so just create a `shared` module and then use that `sharedModule` at every place you want to use that `generic` component. Just create a `shared` `module` and generate `commentsComponent` in that like this

directory structure

```
shared(module)
  components
    commentsComponent
      comments.component.ts
      comments.component.html
  share.module.ts
```

and inside of `shared.module.ts` just do this

```
declarations: [CommentsComponent]
exports: [commentsComponent]
```

Include your `shared` components in `exports` array so that you can access in your any module.

Now when you want to use your `comments.component`  let say in your `module1` so just do this in your `module1.module.ts`

```
import { SharedModule } from 'path-to-shared-module';

imports : [SharedModule]
```

In this way you can use your shared components in multiple modules of your app.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for your reply. If child component is declared in a parent module, and a child module is imported into the parent module, will the child module be able to access the child component?